# IP Address of Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

A client wants to open up their firewall to allow our app on their server to connect to our Azure SQL Server by adding the IP Address of the Azure SQL Server to their firewall.

Of course on our side we add their static IP address to our Azure SQL Server's firewall to allow inbound access.

The part were they are requesting the IP address of our Azure SQL Server:

> Please can you supply us the Public IP of this server in Azure as this IP you have given is a Private IP.
> We restrict traffic to SQL server to only allow from approved IPs.
> Can you furnish us with the External Server IP and the Ports the system uses so we can create Firewall rules for you.

How would I go about getting the IP address for the Azure SQL Server?

Could it be referring to this list: [Gateway IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, article describes connectivity from outside to Azure SQL Server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture#connectivity-from-outside-of-azure

and range of IP addresses of the Gateway that pass traffic from outside to Azure SQL Server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture#gateway-ip-addresses

Answer (score 0):

Try to open powershell... run tnc {xxx-xxx-xxx}-sqlserver.database.windows.net -port 1433

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).